# Shader in editor and game different output

Tags: c#, shader, unity-game-engine

I'm playing with unity 2017 with 2d, so to improve perfomance of game I try to use mask with light(shader) to make interesting view. And got problem that doesn't found any solution in internet.
Shader I used [2DLightShader](https://github.com/sygmajji/unity-scripts/blob/master/shaders/2DLightShader.shader)
Look at the picture:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ctLV.png)
So, anybody can explain me please why so different in editor and actual in game?

Comment: Does the shader depend on camera distance?

Comment: Interesting question. Changed camera Z axis and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found in camera settings HDR mode on. Then checked GraphicsSettings and in it HDR mode was off. That's why in game such fade light. So enabled HDR mode and it works perfect!